# Save file that customer submits through a form

Tags: magento-1, controllers, forms, upload

I have a form:

```
<form class="customDocs" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customdocuments/index/send') ?>">
   <h2>Upload Seller's Permit Here:</h2>
   <input type="file" name="sellerPermit" id="sellerPermit">
   <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Upload Documents" name="submit">
</form>
```

Which is submitted to my controller:

```
class Sean_CustomDocuments_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function sendAction(){ //handles the form submit
        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        $info = pathinfo('/media/custom_documents/seller_permits/' . $post['seller_permit']);
        $ext = $info['extension'];
        $filename = $post['seller_permit'] . $ext;
        $target = '/media/custom_documents/seller_permits' . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($post['sellerPermit'], $target);

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your Documents have been updated!'));//add success message.
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
}
```

I want to save their file into this directory:
/media/custom_documents/seller_permits/
Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with **[@ForgeOnline Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/144595/3535)**, you need to do following changes.

You are collecting file input in wrong way in your controller. Currently what you are doing is this:

```
$post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
$info = pathinfo('/media/custom_documents/seller_permits/' . $post['seller_permit']);
```

This is wrong because. `$post` variable only holds `$_GET` and `$_POST` data. It does not hold `$_FILES` data which is where file data from forms are kept.

So you need following code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['sellerPermit']['name']) && $_FILES['sellerPermit']['name'] != '') {
    try {   
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('sellerPermit');
        // Any extention would work
        //$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('csv','jpeg','gif','png'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'custom_documents'.DS.'seller_permits';
        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['sellerPermit']['name'] );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($e->getMessage());        
        }

}
```

### EDIT

To change file name, you need to do this:

```
//here I added new name same as scopeId
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$ext     = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newname = 'your_file_new_name' . $ext;
$result  = $uploader->save($path, $newname);
```

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: quick question what does the DS in the $path stand for and what does it mean?

Comment: and if i wanted to rename the file how would i go about doing so?

Comment: @CodingMageSheen Please see my edit.

Comment: perfect ty you're the best

Comment: DS stands for DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Answer (score 2):

Your form is missing with attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. ie,

```
<form class="customDocs" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```